# Multiple CSS Background Fallbacks

Tags: css, background

Want to do the next css background fallbacks:

```
1. Solid color
2. If linear-gradient supports by browser, change background to gradient
3. If RGBa supports by browser, change background to half transparent linear-gradient
```

This is easy, but:

```
4. If image loaded, change background to image, otherwise use fallbacks.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read exactly what you posted, take that same order and type that out in in your css declaration.

1) Most browsers reconigze a solid background, and will continue on to the next property.

2) If it understands the linear gradient property, it will continue on to RGBA. If not, It will stop at background: Black.

If the browser doesn't recognize a certain property, it skips it until it finds one it does. For example.

```
div {
        background: black;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));


    }
```

I hope this makes sense :)

Always place your fallback code at the top of your "questionable" css styles.

As far as the background image, it goes exactly the same way. Put the fallback code at the top of your properties. Example.

```
    div {
    background: black;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d321f809ba58efc88780b60ec431b43?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is wrong solution (of course, before asking question on stackowerflow, I tried all simple variants, also this variant)
 
https://jsfiddle.net/qnqqLmz4/ - This gives black in chrome

Comment: I am sorry, posted not full text of comment. Updated.

Comment: @LanKing I'm sorry I posted quick answer late at night . I actually wrote it backwards I apologize. It's the opposite of what I put.  You want to put backgroun:black first and then the rest after. The browser always reads the last property in the list. If a browser doesn't understand anything after background black, it will stop a background black. That should do it. I apologize.

Comment: I'll update my answer in a few minutes if that helps you. Try that out and it should work. 

Background: black;
background: linear;
background: rgba;

Is that what you mean ?

Comment: This is good if you have no background-image in the stack. If you have, but url is incorrect, you will see transparent bg.

Comment: Send me a js fiddle with a url to a hosted image somewhere and I'll take a look at what your seeing.

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry about that was late at night when I wrote it.

Comment: As far as your js fiddle, you don't have to separate image url and linear gradients.

I updated your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qnqqLmz4/3/

As you see, using chrome, because chrome understands all the properties, it applies each and every one of them. If a browser didn't understand linear gradients or rgba, it would stop at background:black. 

You won't see that part unless you test in a browser that doesn't understand linear gradients or rgba. Does this help?

Comment: Updated my top answer and also updated your fiddle at jsfiddle.net/qnqqLmz4/3 . Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Of course, I tried this :-) This is not solution, because you got mixed background. If you use transparent png, you will see that it mixes with linear-gradient.

Comment: Hmmm ok, sounds to me like your looking for a javascript solution then. There's no way that I know of to test if a image loaded successfully or not without using javascript or php. Maybe someone else can chime in. Hope the best!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! JS is superflarity for this task imho.